# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory NextJs

Tags: node.js, next.js

I get this error whenever I run yarn dev, Ive no configuration running, i"ve tried running set node options, my space size is 2096, I tried increasing it to 4096 but it failed

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory        
 1: 00007FF798047C4F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114207
 2: 00007FF797FD5EC6 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF797FD6D7D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF79890B6CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7988F5CAD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF79879907C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF7987A5D29 v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1129
 8: 00007FF7987A2CFA v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2842
 9: 00007FF798795959 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2137
10: 00007FF798793B10 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2000
11: 00007FF7987B1820 v8::internal::FreeListManyCached::Reset+1408
12: 00007FF7987B1ED5 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+37
13: 00007FF7987C3E7E v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray+46
14: 00007FF7987C6ABA v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+74
15: 00007FF7987C6D13 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithMap+35
16: 00007FF7985CF13E v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::New<v8::internal::Isolate>+110
17: 00007FF7988C4B00 v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle+167248
18: 00007FF7988C0A3D v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle+150669
19: 00007FF7988C0520 v8::internal::Builtins::code_handle+149360
20: 00007FF7989994C1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494673
21: 000001FB02CAFF89
```